# Grapheme generation - time vs. memory complexity

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, bitmap, complexity-theory

I am writing a program to generate 'multigraph' data from text files, which are basically mappings between graphemes and their frequency of occurrence in the text file, for example:

```
aaaa : 0
aaab : 0
aaac : 0
...
thel : 10
them : 250
...
zzzz : 0
```

The basic idea is that you can then 'score' a string based on the multigraph data to test how closely it resembles the language of the text file. The scoring function must be extremely fast. Therefore, I was hoping to achieve direct access to the data by using an n-dimensional array. For example:

```
data[n('t')][n('h')][n('e')][n('m')]
```

Where n(char) is a function that normalises a character such that a -> 0, b -> 1, c -> 2, etc. Anyway, here lies the problem: 26^n gets large, very quickly! If I use 4 bytes per element, the following memory is required for different values of n:

1. 104  B
2. 3   KB
3. 69  KB
4. 2   MB
5. 45  MB
6. 1   GB
7. 30  GB
8. 778 GB

So it seems that when n > 3, the stack runs out of memory, and when n > 6, most heaps run out of memory. Ideally, I'd like to be able to generate multigraph files of any reasonable length- up to 10 or so. Any ideas how I could achieve this?

<strike>I thought about the possibility of using less than one byte for each element of the array. I'd only really need to index 'a-z' and maybe a few special characters (spaces, punctuation), so could probably get away with 5 bits (0 - 31). Is this possible? I'd potentially save 38% memory if I could. How do you think this would affect time-complexity?</strike>

One option is to use a hashing function rather than an array. This would mean that I'm only using memory on keys that actually exist, rather than 'qxzf' which is always going to have a frequency of 0. The memory requirement would be greatly reduced, but I'm concerned that the time-complexity would be severely affected. What do you think?

Perhaps I could use some kind of tree data structure? Graphemes lend themselves to that sort of representation, but again, time-complexity would surely take a hit. I think it would take 'n' steps to access data, rather than 1.

Finally, I'm considering multi-threading the scoring function. I'd rather not allocate a copy of the data for each thread. Do you think it's possible to use a bit or two in combination with Peterson's algorithm for locking an element?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you done any benchmarks on using simply Dictionary<string, int>? It might be slower but for large n the space savings would make it better than preallocating a space for every possible string ahead of time

Comment: I'll try a benchmark tomorrow. I'd imagine it would be several times slower though. It would have to do a string comparison, on each scoring.

Comment: I'm with Brandon.  Prototype it simple first to get a real world starting point and add coomplexity as needed.  As an aside, I'd guess that hashing would still be close enough to constant time lookups to be viable (and probably more cache friendly as well.)

Comment: @Christopher: regarding multi-threading, how much of the scoring function is within the critical section(s)? Does the string-to-be-tested get its own grapheme frequency structure? Do you want to multi-thread the scoring for a single string, or is each thread supposed to score different strings? Does the scoring function need write access to the shared grapheme frequency structure(s)?

Comment: The scoring function would be multi-threaded, with each thread taking on different strings to score. Once the multigraph data is generated, it remains constant. The CR for the scoring function would be reading from the data structure only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Trie](http://bhavin.directi.com/to-trie-or-not-to-trie-a-comparison-of-efficient-data-structures/)s offer good time-space tradeoffs. A plain [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), where each node (e.g. for the prefix "iq") has an array of children pointers indexed by the next character in the string (e.g. 'x'), will still have wasted space in the form of nulls in the child pointer array, but you will save space as there is no branch rooted in that prefix (e.g. "iqx"). Other tries reduce the amount of space but increase the time complexity (though not necessarily by much) by storing only pointers to children that exist, which requires searching the children pointers, usually in logarithmic time in the number of children. Some tries of the latter type store all the pointers for a given prefix in a single node; others (such as [ternary search tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search_tree)) use multiple nodes.

Lookup with tries is roughly O(n), but since *n* is rather small, the actual performance could be fast enough for your purposes. Depending on how you're counting things, multidimensional array access is itself O(n), as looking up a key of *n* characters involves evaluating a polynomial with *n* terms (`data[a1]...[an] == data + sum(i=1..n, ai * 256i-1)`).

If the space requirements are still too high, even for virtual memory, then you'll need to store much of the structure on disk, such as [B+ trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B+_tree) allow. In this case, the B+ tree would provide the implementation underlying a hash table. This will, of course, cause quite a performance hit, but is unavoidable once the memory requirements reach a certain level.

> I thought about the possibility of using less than one byte to index each dimension of the array.

It's perfectly possible to reduce the number of potential array indices this way. You could do this in addition to using a specialized data structure. For example, this will reduce the fan-out of nodes in a trie, reducing the number of null pointers.

You'd need a function to map characters to array keys, which will add only slightly to the time complexity. Using a table lookup will result in a low constant-time increase and small space increase (~256 bytes).

You may also need to pre-process the sample data and strings-to-be-tested to filter out/map invalid characters (such as converting upper case to lower case) at a time complexity linear in the length of the strings.

> Finally, I'm considering multi-threading the scoring function.

The gains here depend on how much of the scoring function's calculation is spent outside of reading from the grapheme structure. If little time is spent outside of that, then the threads will spend most of their time waiting and you won't see much of a performance improvement. [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) applies here.

Based on your comment, the multi-threaded scoring function might not need locks for read-only access. As long as read-only access doesn't alter the structure itself, all state to traverse the structure is contained entirely within the read function, any functions the read function calls (e.g. a hash function) are thread safe and the entire structure fits in available memory, then there shouldn't be a conflict if multiple threads read from the tree at the same time.

If you use a disk-backed approach (such as with B+ trees), the last requirement won't hold. In that case, you'll probably need locking around the code that processes a disk block so as to prevent thrashing.

Comment: I'm leaning towards a solution where the data structure to be used is dependent upon the amount of memory available. Perhaps for small values of n, a n-dimensional array could be used, for intermediate values, a hash map could be used and for large values, a trie could be used.

There was a little uncertainty as to whether a hash map or a trie is faster for reads (that's all that matters in this case). I guess that's the sort of thing I should benchmark?

Answer (score 1):

A [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is likely to be as fast as your method (n array lookups vs n tree-node traversals) and save a ton of space.  A hash would work also and might be faster on lookup, but will require more space.